# Can an OSGi bundle or package depend on multiple versions of another bundle or package?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

Can a OSGi bundle have two dependencies, each on a different version of the same OSGi bundle?

Can a OSGi package have two dependencies, each on a different version of the same OSGi package?

(I am trying to learn OSGi from the ground up. This question is just intended to help me understand the basic concepts. From reading online articles about OSGi services, I gather that such dependencies certainly wouldn't be recommended practice. But are they possible at all?)

*(Update: rephrased the two questions.)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. OSGi provides a consistent class space for a bundle. This means that it is only exposed to a single class of a given name. So a bundle cannot simultaneously see more than one version of a package at a time.

This does not mean that ClassCastExceptions are impossible since code your bundle is directly dependent on, can expose objects from their dependencies to your bundle. The proper use of uses constraints on export packages is important to prevent this.

Comment: Where is this documented? (I know this is a new question ...)

Comment: Wait, I found it (OSGi Service Platform
Core Specification 4.3.0, page 38).

Answer (score 1):

> Can a OSGi bundle depend on two different versions of another OSGi bundle at the same time?
>   Can an OSGi package depend on two different versions of another OSGi package at the same time?

Sort of. You can depend on ranges or specific versions of another OSGI bundle or package like this:

Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.3,2.0)"

Not sure if that applies in the first section because bundles should not depend on other bundles, only packages. This is what 'Require-Bundle' does but is suggested you don't use it. Require-Bundle takes versions as well so theoretically it should support version ranges.

Once your OSGi bundle is resolved within OSGi, it will find the package of any of those versions. However, it can't resolve a package (org.osgi.framework) to two separate bundles (one which provides version 1.9 and one which provides 1.8). It will choose the most recent version based on SemVer.

If you try to specify it twice in Import-Package, you will get a 'Duplicate Import' error.

Comment: I knew this answer would come and I did not know how to avoid it. I do *not* want to know how to specify a flexible version range for a *single* dependency on a package. What I want to know is whether it is possible to have *two different* dependencies on *different* versions of the *same* package. It is *not true* that specifying the same package name twice with a different version specification results in an error: with Eclipse Juno and Equinox, MANIFEST.MF validates, the project compiles and runs, only the bundle refuses to install.

Comment: That is why I specified both, because i wasn't sure what exactly you were asking. 

That said: It /is/ specifying an error if it refuses to install. A MANIFEST.mf being validated doesn't validate the individual fields of the Import-Package. That only gets validated on resolution of the bundle dependencies, which happens at bundle install or startup time. I'm using felix but here are my results trying to run with version 1.3 and 1.4 of osgi.framework. 

https://gist.github.com/sheenobu/6512285

Comment: Thank you very much! I suspected as much and the spec appears to state it, but not very clearly. This fully explains what I'm seeing (although I'm surprised that validation doesn't check it).

Comment: The trouble with this Eclipse environment is that it's throwing so many unrelated warnings and errors that any *Duplicate Import* error has scrolled beyond the size of the console buffer before I get a chance to see it ...